# Read full pipe input from awk

Tags: awk

As I understand, awk can be used in two ways. You can pass a list of files as arguments to it or you can use it in a pipe. I try to use it with a list of files as arguments, so the `BEGIN` and `END` blocks are executed only once for all files. But I have the problem that my files need to be decrypted before I want to pass them to awk. So I have the following setup with pipes:

`find . -name "*.gpg" -exec sh -c "gpg -d {} | awk -f process.awk" \;`

now the `BEGIN` and `END` blocks in `process.awk` are executed for every file, which is not what I want. Is there a way to decypt the files that get passed to awk so that the blocks execute only once? Update: As I also need the filename in `process.awk` I think it is better to get the file contents indiviually, but then my requirement that `BEGIN` and `END` are executed once for all found files is violated, right?

Comment: It's not clear if you want the contents of all files passed to awk as if it were one file or not. Please [edit] your question to clarify that and include some sample input and expected output that'd demonstrat your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file names don't contain newlines:

```
while IFS= read -r fname; do
    gpg -d "$fname"
done < <(find . -name '*.gpg') |
awk -f process.awk
```

To do what you now say you want and pass each file name to awk the simplest thing to do is probably (assuming bash 4.* for `readarray` or `mapfile` otherwise write a loop to populate `fnames[]`):

```
readarray -t fnames < <(find . -name '*.gpg')
for fname in "${fnames[@]}"; do
    gpg -d "$fname" |
    awk -v fname="$fname" -v tot="${#fnames[@]}" -v nr="$((++nr))" -f process.awk
done
```

and that way you have each file name in `fname` and you can test for `nr==1` in the `BEGIN` and `nr==tot` in the `END` sections to execute the code there or not:

```
BEGIN {
    if (nr==1) {
        do BEGIN stuff
    }
}
{ do common stuff }
END {
    if (nr==tot) {
        do END stuff
    }
}
```

Or if you have room for the temp files you can loop calling `gpg` and write all output to a temp directory of files of the same names and call awk on each of those without necessarily changing `process.awk`:

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d) &&
while IFS= read -r fname; do
    gpg -d "$fname" > "$tmpdir"/"$fname"
done < <(find . -name '*.gpg') &&
awk -f process.awk "$tmpdir"/* &&
rm -rf "$tmpdir"
```

Comment: Like this, the files are not separated anymore. You have only one big "file" (stdin). Ńot sure, but I understand it, that OP wants `awk -f process.awk <(gpg -d file1) <(gpg -d file2) ...`

Comment: @pLumo not sure I understand the comment. AFAIK the OP WANTS the contents of all files passed to awk at once.

Comment: @EdMorton : he updated and says he needs the filenames in awk, apparently. I do not use gawk much but is there some kind of "pre-processing" applicable on the filename currently process by awk? that could call gpg -d on it? thus awk would have the proper filename & be able to read the uncompressed version, one after the other?

Comment: @OlivierDulac the 2nd and 3rd scripts I posted do pass each file name to awk. There's nothing specifically like you suggest built in BUT you can do something kinda hacky... I'll update my answer to show it anyway since you asked.

Comment: @OlivierDulac when I started writing it I realized just what a horrible hack it is and it has no benefits over either of the solutions I already posted so I'm not going to do it.

Comment: @EdMorton : I appreciate the attempt, and I'm glad you kept it simple in the end (I was just wondering if GNU awk offered a simple way to pre-process input files, but apparently not)